# .NET Socket Send & Receive Not Matching

Tags: vb.net, sockets, network-programming

I have these following lines to send bytes using socket

```
Dim server As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

Dim myIp As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("myIP")

Dim ip As New IPEndPoint(myIp, Int32.Parse("myPort"))

server.Connect(ip)

server.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Halo")
```

These are the lines I use to receive

```
Dim data(255) As Byte

Dim bytesReceived As Integer = socket.Receive(buffer)

Dim stringData As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)
```

My problem:

As in the code, I am supposed to retrieved "Halo". Instead I keep receiving sth like "[]". Can someone give me advise on this?

Comment: Yes, these are all the relevant code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to receive data on a socket, you need to use the `Socket.Receive` method. Here's an example of what you need to do:

```
'Dim sock As Socket
Dim buffer(255) As Byte 'the data will be stored here
Dim bytesReceived As Integer = socket.Receive(buffer) 'will be used to see how many bytes were received

'not all bytes in the buffer contain data, so only use the number equal to the number received
Dim result As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesReceived)
```

I would recommend using a larger buffer, though, such as 4096.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx contains a few synchronous and asynchronous socket examples.

Comment: Omg this is awkward, I do have that line in my code. I just forgot to type it into the question. haha. anyway thx for the suggestion..

Comment: Btw, I tried to follow your whole style and I still can't retrieve the correct string. it still produces "[]" anyway thx

Comment: The code you provided isn't enough to solve the problem, though. You'll need to post more or see if you can fix it with help from MSDN's example code.